# Change padding of usercontrol based on ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, scrollviewer

I have a usercontrol that hosts some content inside a scrollviewer, when the window is resized the vertical scroll is set up to show automatically, this all works fine.

I want a trigger on the ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility property, that changes the Padding of the actual usercontrol. This is my code right now, why is it not working?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Something.CustomizableView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Something"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TheScroll,Path=ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
```

Here is my ScrollViewer + ItemsControl

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="TheScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding ContentModules}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentTemplateSelector}"
                Background="White">
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0 0 0 50" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this style for the scroll viewer, and remove the style from the user control:

```
<Thickness x:Key="NoScrollPaddingThickness"
            Left="20"
            Top="20"
            Bottom="20"
            Right="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="WithScrollPaddingThickness"
            Left="20"
            Top="20"
            Bottom="20"
            Right="0">
</Thickness>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="{StaticResource NoScrollPaddingThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Corner"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}"
                                Grid.Row="1" />
                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                            CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                            CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                            Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
                                Cursor="Arrow"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                Minimum="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                Cursor="Arrow"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                Minimum="0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                                Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Padding"
                                Value="{StaticResource WithScrollPaddingThickness}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

### EDIT

To make it more compact, we can use the style only - we don't really need a template here:

```
<Thickness x:Key="NoScrollPaddingThickness"
            Left="20"
            Top="20"
            Bottom="20"
            Right="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="WithScrollPaddingThickness"
            Left="20"
            Top="20"
            Bottom="20"
            Right="0">
</Thickness>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="{StaticResource NoScrollPaddingThickness}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                 Value="Visible">
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="{StaticResource WithScrollPaddingThickness}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i guess retemplating the entire scrollviewer is a way to go =). Do you know why my original DataTrigger is not triggered?

Comment: Probably different naming scopes, the binding cannot find `ElementName=TheScroll`. Also, the solution above will work for all scroll viewers in the application, not just specific for a view.

Comment: Hi XAMeLi, thanks for your nice examples, I checked it as answered. The solution works fine for me, but not 100%, since the padding needs to be around the usercontrol and not just the scrollviewer, since there is other content in the control that needs to be seperated from the overall layout.